# PXE boot - can't access BIOS

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, boot, bios, pxe

The issue I'm having is with a Dell Vostro 3360, Windows 7 64 Bit +  Ubuntu 12.04 (Dual Boot).
Everything worked perfectly until one day after a windows update it started showing this message on start up (after the Dell logo):

`Intel UNDI PXE-2.0 (build 083) 
Copyright (C)...

For Atheros PCIE Ethernet Controller v2.1.1.1(12/23/11)
Check cable connection!

PXE-M0F: Exiting Intel PXE ROM.`

and then Ubuntu loads immediately instead of showing GRUB menu.
If I press Esc right before Ubuntu is loading I do get the GRUB screen but only with Ubuntu option (together with Memory test and recovery mode options)

If I connect the laptop to a network with a cable it tries to connect to DHCP instead of showing the `Check cable connection!` message (with an ASCII progress bar) but never succeeds.

I can access the Windows partitions and files from Ubuntu.

Pressing F12 or F2 does not do anything and I cannot access the BIOS options.

I tried fixing GRUB from recovery mode and with Boot-Repair but it didn't change anything.

I tried to remove the hard drive and boot to BIOS but F12 and F2 still didn't work and the laptop got stuck in a loop of the same PXE message and then reboot.

I tried removing the coin battery and replacing it hoping it will change anything.

I searched the web for a solution but nothing came up with a method I didn't already try.

How can I disable the PXE boot and restore access to the BIOS again?

Thank you.

Comment: PXE is the ability to boot from a network. It requires a PXE/TFTP/DHCP server with correct config. You can disable network boot through BIOS. If Windows is missing from GRUB then you will need to edit its menu files and update GRUB so it updates the boot sectors so it knows about Windows. http://askubuntu.com/questions/271323/windows-missing-from-grub-menu

Comment: Thanks @BigChris, unfortunately I can't access the BIOS to change this option. Actually this is the main issue I'm concerned about.

Comment: Is the device a PC or laptop? If PC then you can take out the CMOS battery for a few minutes whilst the mains cable is also unplugged, then reconnect the battery then the mains (in that order!) and when you boot the computer the first thing it should do is go to the BIOS setup screen.

Answer (score 1):

You may have trouble accessing the BIOS from a warm boot but not a cold one because on the new fast systems the the quick boot is enabled and it boots though. After the bios update it was probably reset to BIOS Defaults which includes that setting. It also reordered your boot order enabling PXE boot. once you see the PXE boot message you are already past where you would need to get into the BIOS. Power it on and start tapping F2 (about twice a second) before you see any messages on the screen. you dont want to hold the F2 because it will trigger a stuck key message and dump the keyboard buffer when reaching the point where it would normally ask you to press F2.

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happened to me. I actually removed the CMOS battery and was too quick to replace it. Spent another couple of hours wasting time before trying again and leaving out for 1 min before replacing. Immediately started back up after BIOS reset.